# Static serving on express js not working when also using custom middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web, middleware

I am trying to write a middleware for my express js website so that I can use subdomains. I also want to use static image, css, and js serving. My HTML pages load just fine but whenever I try to call a .js file, I get a long page load time and the js doesn't load.

Any help is appreciated, thanks! :)

```
app.use("/assets", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "assets")));

app.get("*", (req, res, next) => {

let host = req.get("host").split(".");
console.log(req.originalUrl);

let url = req.originalUrl.split("/");
url.shift();
console.log(url);

if (host.length > 2) {
    res.send("myWebsite.com");
} else {
    const pages = Page.getPages();
    pages.forEach(page => {
        if ((url[0] == "" ? "home" : url[0] ?? "home").toLowerCase() == page.name) {
            if (url.length == 1 || (url.length == 2 && url[1] == "")) {
                page.publish(res);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

});

Comment: To help with `express.static()` issues for a JS file, we need to know exactly what the `<script>` tag `href` looks like in the web page, what the full URL is of the containing web page and where the target JS file is in your server file system relative to the directory where your server is running from.

Comment: Also, what does `page.publish(res)` do?

Comment: Thanks for responding jfriend00! The publish function executes this line of code: `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, this.path))`. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/z0oaJGr) is my file structure. I hope that helps :)

Comment: Still need to see the actual `src` from a `<script>` tag and then see where that js file is in your server file hierarchy. Those two plus a couple other things have to match and is the most common error in using `express.static()`.

Comment: Oh ok :) Here's the repository, I figured I'd just provide all the source code (minus the sensitive information of course) haha. https://github.com/markRegg/website

Answer (score 0):

So, in `Pages.html`, you have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/Pages.js"></script>
```

That looks like it would generally be compatible with your `express.static()` statement (shown below) to load Pages.js from your `assets/js` folder:

```
app.use("/assets", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "assets")));
```

But, then that `Pages.js` script immediately starts out with this:

```
import Page from '../../Page.js';
```

That will not work when requested by the browser.  Remember paths in `import` statements from Javascript running in the browser are relative to the current URL of the web page.  The browser will attempt to combine that relative URL with the URL of the web page and then make a request to your server for that newly constructed URL.

In this case, you'll end up with something like a request for `http://somehost/../../Page.js`.   But, you don't have any route in your server that will handle that.  By default `express.static()` skips any routes that contain `../` because that can be a nasty security issues (allowing attackers to fetch things around your server file system).  So, you'll probably end up with a 404 error when trying to fetch that file.

ALL files you want the browser to be able to load, including imports embedded within other JS files must be in your public `assets` folder (or some other folder you've explicitly enabled public access to with something like `express.static()`).

FYI, if you look in the browser console, you probably see error messages that would have indicated to you where to look for the error.

Answer (score -1):

__dirname is an environment variable that tells you the absolute path of the directory containing the currently executing file. You have to make sure that the final bundle (your asset folder) is present in that directory. Try to hard code the assets absolute path, if it works then use the below snippet instead:-

```
app.use("/assets", "express.static(process.cwd() + '/assets'));
```